# Making a variable that has code inside of it?

Tags: c++, variables

Is there a way I can make a variable in C++ that has code inside of it that I can run later?

For example:

```
string code = "cout << "Hello World" << endl;"?
```

Or make a file or Notepad file that can be run later? Like if someone adds an employee to a program, it'll make a file and add all of the employee's information. Then later on when the program user says "I want to see that employee" by either writing their name or a unique ID, it shows all of the employee's information.

Thank you.

Comment: You are asking "how do I write a program?". It will be put on hold as too broad.

Comment: c++ is not a scripting language...

Comment: You do know that nobody would ever write a program that turns data into code. If you want to store and load employee information, you don't write it as code. It's data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is to use #define preprocessor directive to create a macro:-

```
#define code cout << "Hello World" << endl;
```

Now whereever you use the word 'code', it will be replaced by cout << "Hello World" << endl;

eg:

```
int main()
{
    code
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's relatively new syntax.

```
std::string msg = "Hello world";
auto code = [&std::cout, =msg]() {std::cout << msg;};

// Now we can pass code about as a variable.

code(); // runs it, even if std::cout and msg has gone out of scope
```

The advantage is that a comparison function, or a key access function, or similar can be attached to a bigger structure. You can also build entire programs out of lambdas, but that's getting rather theoretical.

However you must specify the C++ code at compile time. You can't compile C++ on the fly (yet).

Comment: `You can't compile C++ on the fly (yet).` I hope you'll never be able to. That would be a security nightmare.

Comment: I have seen programs that work by generating some C++ code, writing it to a  file, and then invoking the C++ compiler to compile that code into an executable (or shared library), and then loading and running that code.  The authors of those programs should be permanently kept away from computers, for their own safety :)

Comment: Lisp and related language allow the creation of functions on the fly. However it's a difficult facility to use effectively. In C++ it is relatively easy to add scripting (see Minibasic https://sourceforge.net/projects/minibasic/ by me for how to easily add scripting to C/C++). It's an open debate whether allowing the user to "softcode" is a good design pattern or not, but some program are built on it.

Comment: Thanks guys for the help!